# Casting a List Interface to a custom List class

Tags: c#

I currently have a custom class that extends and IList as such

```
public class CustomList<T> : IList<T>
{
}
```

Now somewhere in my code I have this

```
IList<string> _myList = new CustomList<string>();
```

My question is how do I convert _myList to CustomList ?

Comment: Have you tried this: `CustomList<string> customList = (CustomList<string>)_myList;`

Comment: `var g = _myList as CustomList<string>;` Check if it is `null` afterwards (in case it **wasn't** a `CustomList`.

Comment: Did you get chance to look into my answer. Is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try C# 7 feature i.e [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching),

Like

```
if(_myList is CustomList<string> customList)
{
 //Your code 
}
```

As @TanvirArjel suggested, Explicit type conversion supported by C#6 and below version

```
CustomList<string> customList = (CustomList<string>)_myList;
```